# Enable BroadcastReceivers for plugin-style functionality

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am attempting to create a system where I have certain factory-basic functionality.

I intend 3rd party developers to be able to extend this functionality with their own code.

This is intended to work by firing off a Broadcast in certain situations where I would like a 3rd party App to receive data that it can use.

This system works, but the issue I have is that since version 3.1, the App needs to be run by a user in order to enable BroadcastReceivers. I was hoping that I could let these plugins exist without a launcher / default Activity, so that users do not need to clog their launcher with icons for plugins. Extra Activities would be defined for settings, but that would be called from my App-ecosystem.

tl;dr:
How can I enable a BroadcastReceiver in a newly installed App with as little user intervention as possible (ideally, without being located in the Launcher).

Comment: so there will be the main_settings app in the launcher and 3rd party developed should just receive the broadcasts without the need to be launched?

Comment: There should be no activities from the 3rd party App visible in the launcher. That would cause too much clutter. The 3rd party App(s) should receive Broadcasts without needing to be launched. The 3rd party App can then do what it wants with the data I have given it. It could display an activity to the user with options, etc. But that is out of scope.

Comment: As far as I understood from your question, as long as the 3rd party devs proper configure the manifest, there's no need to launch their app to enable the receivers. It's already in the manifest.

Comment: The problem is in version 3.1 of Android, they introduced added security features. Please see this passage of a vogella.com tutorial: http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidBroadcastReceiver/article.html#broadcastreceiver_platformfilter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, the Android 3.1+ limitation is for implicit `Intents`. Explicit `Intents` -- where you set the `ComponentName` of the receiver -- should work without issue.

So, the question now becomes: how are you really communicating with multiple plugins?

If your intention was to send a single broadcast that everyone can receive, that will trip over the Android 3.1 issue. You would need to directly invoke some component in the third-party app yourself to enable it, such as starting one of its activities from your UI via an explicit `Intent`, or sending a broadcast to one of its components directly via an explicit `Intent`.

If your intention was to send a broadcast specifically to individual plugins, then you already have some sort of way of discovering plugins (e.g., monitoring added packages and looking for a component with certain `<meta-data>`). In that case, you can arrange to derive the explicit `Intent` to use (e.g., it's the component with the `<meta-data>`) and should be able to broadcast to it explicitly.

If you are finding that explicit `Intents` do not work due to the Android 3.1 "stopped state" limitation, please let me know, as I would want to do some more investigation.

Comment: Perfect. I hadn't considered explicitly setting the ComponentName. That solved my issue. For future reference, the way I am doing it is that I get a list of receivers that support my App: pm.queryBroadcastReceivers(intent, 0). I can then pick one, and with ComponentName, I can send a Broadcast to it specifically.

Comment: @Knossos: Oh, yeah, that'll work too, at the cost of N broadcasts vs. just the one. If that proves to be too much overhead, you could look to optimize matters, such that you only do the explicit `Intent` when there is a plugin that you do not recognize (though that might get tricky if the user uninstalls and reinstalls the plugin...).

Answer (score 0):

oh, I was not aware of this new security feature. What a bummer...

but now that I understood the details of the question, I'll sugest an answer, but not sure it will work, you'll have to test it for yourself.

Maybe you can on your app receive the [PACKAGE_ADDED broadcast](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_PACKAGE_ADDED), on this Receiver, you'll query the package manager for this newly added package and check if it have an intent-filter for your broadcast, if it does, then your app should explicitly launch some component of that 3rd party app, so it can be 'initialised' by the 3.1 system restriction.

That might mean that you'll need to change the interaction with your 3rd party developers so they have a standard component your app can always fire, but it does seem like a feasible work-around.